# How to apply linear gradient style to react native screen?

Tags: react-native, linear-gradients

I need to apply following style to app screen.

```
fobackground: linear-gradient(180deg, #00599B 0%, #002F52 100%);
```

Using react-native-linear-gradient, I tried following code, but not sure how can I use 0% and 100% values provided above in style.

```
<LinearGradient
  colors={['#00599B', '#002F52']}
  useAngle={true}
  angle={180}
  style={{
    flex: 1,
  }}>
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign in with Facebook</Text>
</LinearGradient>
```

Comment: How is the output different from what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using `rgba` colors:

I converted your HEX to the RGBA colors:

```js
<LinearGradient
  colors={['rgba(0, 89, 155, 0)', 'rgba(0, 47, 82, 1)']}
  useAngle={true}
  angle={180}
  style={{
    flex: 1,
  }}>
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign in with Facebook</Text>
</LinearGradient>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the percentages to define where the color gradients start and stop through the `location` prop. The first color corresponds to the first value, and so on.

```
<LinearGradient
  locations={[0,1]}
  colors={['#00599B', '#002F52']}
  useAngle= true 
  angle= 180,
  style={{
      flex: 1,
  }}>
     <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign in with Facebook</Text>
</LinearGradient>
```

Learn more here at the [official documentation](https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient#locations)